# ffmpeg - offset cropped part of a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, crop

**Problem:**

- I have a video that is made of two separate Videos next to each other

```
-------------------------
|   -------             |
|   |vid2 |             |
|   |     |    vid1     |
|   -------             |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
-------------------------
```

- the 2nd video is delayed in respect to the first, that's why I want to offset the second video by the difference

For the cropping part, I figured using the [crop-option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) might work, but I don't quite know, how to put the video back together, so that the cropped part of the video ends up at the same place as before, i.e. how to set the position, while overlaying the 2 videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the vid2 window is 2.5 seconds late, is of size WxH and is located at (X,Y) from top-left corner of full frame.

You would use

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "split=2[v1][v2];[v2]trim=2.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,crop=W:H:X:Y[v2];[v1][v2]overlay=X:Y" -c:a copy out.mp4
```